# Hibernate multiple natural id within an entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1

I have a jpa entity "user" which has 2 business keys username and email. These 2 fields are unique and i have tried to define both fields as naturalId with @NaturalId, however when i search the user entity by passing only username or email,  hibernate throw an exception complaining about the missing value of a another naturalid because hibernate treated both fields as  a composite natural id. Is this the limitation of hibernate or there is an alternative to solve this error?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user",
       indexes = { @Index(columnList = "login"),
                   @Index(columnList = "email")},
       uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "login" }),
                             @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" })})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalIdCache
public class User {

    @org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId(mutable = true)
    private String login;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId(mutable = true)
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

When I call the code below:

```
User entity = em.unwrap(Session.class)          
    .byNaturalId(User.class)
    .using("login", "abc123")
    .load();
```

or

```
User entity = em.unwrap(Session.class)          
    .byNaturalId(User.class)
    .using("email", "abc123@xyz.com")
    .load();
```

I encountered error complaining about missing of another natural id. I have to set both natural id which was not what i want

```
User entity = em.unwrap(Session.class)          
    .byNaturalId(User.class)
    .using("login", "abc123")
    .using("email", "abc123@xyz.com")
    .load();
```

Comment: Please share the code of your entity as well as selection.

Comment: folks, I have shared the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept does not support more than one business keys.

As you said, annotating multiple properties with [@NaturalId](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/) means that this sole business key consists of multiple properties (javadoc citation):

> This specifies that a property is part of the natural id of the
> entity.

Also rest of the API somewhat communicates the same.
For example  `SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccess` is created via [bySimpleNaturalId(Class entityClass)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#bySimpleNaturalId-java.lang.Class-) and [load](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccess.html#load-java.lang.Object-) in `SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccess` takes value of natural id as an argument. There is no way to specify which natural id.